# Using libtensorflow_cc.so in an existing C++ cmake project

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake

I have an existing C++ cmake project and I want to use tensorflow in it as a third party library. I searched extensively but all the solutions involve installing tensorflow at the end or copying the files to /usr/local directory.

My problem is I don't want to make any changes to the system directories and everything should happen within my project directory.

So, I compiled libtensorflow_cc.so and libtensorflow_framework.so from tensorflow source code and copied into my project directory. I added below code in my CMake to link these libraries.

```
 find_library(tensorflowlibfwk libtensorflow_framework.so 
 PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/lib)
 find_library(tensorflowlibcc libtensorflow_cc.so
 PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/lib)
 target_link_libraries(tensorflowtest ${tensorflowlibfwk} ${tensorflowlibcc})
```

I have no idea about which headers should I include to use the tensorflow in my project ??
Any kind of help please

Comment: "which headers should I include to use the tensorflow in my project?" - Do you ask about which header files you need to **copy** from your tensorflow installation to your project? - Just  copy **all files** from `include/` subdirectory.